# python setup.py install n

Tags: python, windows, version-control, setuptools

I am getting this error when trying to install setuptools_scm-6.0.1, my goal is to install Pyinstaller. I keep getting dependency errors, but can't get through this one. Any ideas? Is is on a closed network, I have to download packages no internet connection in the lab.

```
    C:\Users\img_user\Desktop\dist\setuptools_scm-6.0.1>python setup.py install
    C:\Users\img_user\Desktop\dist\setuptools_scm-6.0.1\src
    <pkg_resources.WorkingSet object at 0x000001DE6AA1E390>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 52, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**scm_config())
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _    setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 372, in __init__
        _      Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 292, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 527, in finalize_options
       ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2346, in require
       items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
      File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 39.0.1 (c:\python37\lib\site-packages), 
    Requirement.parse('setuptools>=45'))'
```

Comment: First, I would recommend you to try installing with `pip install .` instead.